# Deserialize JSON

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, deserialization

I was trying to deserialize below JSON response from an API by using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "candles": [
        ["2015-12-28T09:15:00+0530", 1386.4, 1388, 1381.05, 1385.1, 788],
        ["2015-12-28T09:16:00+0530", 1385.1, 1389.1, 1383.85, 1385.5, 609],
        ["2015-12-28T09:17:00+0530", 1385.5, 1387, 1385.5, 1385.7, 212],
        ["2015-12-28T09:18:00+0530", 1387, 1387.95, 1385.3, 1387.95, 1208],
        ["2015-12-28T09:19:00+0530", 1387, 1387.55, 1385.6, 1386.25, 716],
        ["2015-12-28T09:20:00+0530", 1386.95, 1389.95, 1386.95, 1389, 727],
        ["2015-12-28T09:21:00+0530", 1389, 1392.95, 1389, 1392.95, 291],
        ["2015-12-28T09:22:00+0530", 1392.95, 1393, 1392, 1392.95, 180],
        ["2015-12-28T09:23:00+0530", 1392.95, 1393, 1392, 1392.15, 1869]
        ...
        ["2016-01-01T13:22:00+0530", 1386.4, 1388, 1381.05, 1385.1, 788],
        ["2016-01-01T13:23:00+0530", 1385.1, 1389.1, 1383.85, 1385.5, 613],
        ["2016-01-01T13:24:00+0530", 1385.5, 1387, 1385.5, 1385.7, 212],
        ["2016-01-01T13:25:00+0530", 1387, 1387.95, 1385.3, 1387.95, 1208],
        ["2016-01-01T13:26:00+0530", 1387, 1387.55, 1385.6, 1386.25, 716],
        ["2016-01-01T13:27:00+0530", 1386.95, 1389.95, 1386.95, 1389, 727],
        ["2016-01-01T13:28:00+0530", 1389, 1392.95, 1389, 1392.95, 291],
        ["2016-01-01T13:29:00+0530", 1392.95, 1393, 1392, 1392.95, 180],
        ["2016-01-01T13:30:00+0530", 1392.95, 1393, 1392, 1392.15, 1869]
    ]
  }
}
```

Have created below class to wrap the output but getting error while deserializing :

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class JSON_Model_HistoricalData
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property data As Data
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class Data
    Public Property candles() As List(Of Candles_Data)
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class Candles_Data
    Public Property candles() As String
End Class
```

the error message is :

[image]

can anyone please help where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
**C#**

```
 public class Rootobject
{ 
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public object[][] candles { get; set; }
}
```

**vb**

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property data As Data
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property candles()() As Object
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the changed class `Candles_Data` holding an array of objects

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Candles_Data
    Public Property candles() As Object
End Class
```

as your arrays in the JSON hold strings as well as numbers

Comment: Hi , No luck, it throws same error message after changing as you suggested,

Answer (score 0):

This class should work:

```
Public Class Data
    <JsonProperty("candles")>
    Public Property Candles As Object()()
End Class

Public Class JSON_Model_HistoricalData
    <JsonProperty("status")>
    Public Property Status As String

    <JsonProperty("data")>
    Public Property Data As Data
End Class
```

Here are two tools you might consider using in future to simplify your task:

- [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) - A JSON Validator
- [JSON Utils](http://jsonutils.com/) - Used to generate JSON classes for all .NET languages